# Change standard post format metabox

Tags: post-formats

I added a meta box to my theme (WordPress admin) for video, image, gallery and chat, but I can't add a meta box for the standard post.

When I add post type support for "Standard", the standard post format in admin is duplicated. When selecting the 2nd "Standard" from the list, a meta box is added, but it should do that for the 1st "Standard" and not show it twice.

[image]

Comment: Can you show us the code you are using?

Comment: This might turn out an interesting question, for all is known so far. But please follow the request of @cybmeta and incorporate relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are having here is that `standard` is **not** a [post format](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Formats). `standard` is just assigned to posts that does not have a post format assigned to it. You can also check in your db in `wp_terms`, there is no `post-format-standard` term. You can also do the following to print out a list of all registered post formats

```
$terms = get_terms('post_format','hide_empty=0');
   ?><pre><?php var_dump($terms); ?></pre><?php
```

This is actually one flaw in the post format system. I don't know if this was done on purpose. Unfortunately, you can't add new post formats. So you can't register a `standard` post format. You will need to go and rethink your setup when adding a meta box for posts that does not have a post format assigned to it